# Синтаксическая роль имени числительного

Tags: синтаксис, числительные

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить синтаксическую функцию имени числительного в предложении:

***Квартира его была во втором этаже.***

Имя числительное "втором" будет рассматриваться как согласованное определение внутри синтаксически цельного словосочетания, являющегося обстоятельством места, или оно будет сразу образовывать обстоятельство места с именем существительным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Квартира (какая?)*** - ***во втором этаже*** - часть сказуемого ***была во втором этаже***.

Дробить часть сказуемого ***во втором этаже*** не стоит, так как конструкция ***втором этаже*** представляет собой сочетание числительного с существительным.

Answer (score 0):

Может, кто-то из исследователей и считает, что здесь *второй этаж* нечто синтаксически неразделимое, но самое очевидное решение таково.

Втором — это определение, согласующееся с обстоятельством места (в этаже — кстати, почему не *на*?). Что такое «синтаксически цельное словосочетание», непонятно. Цельность словосочетания ***на*** втором этаже легко может быть нарушена: *на третьем этаже*, *на каком-то этаже*, *на самом неблагополучном этаже*, *на этаже, на котором никто не живет*...